# How can I get merchant_id and other credentails for payzippy payment sandbox setup

Tags: sandbox-solution

How I get the following 3 Test credentials to setup sandbox

1. MID (merchant_id)
2. Secure key (used to determine hash)
3. Secure key id (merchant_key_id)

I got payzippy php-sdk from below mention URL but need test credentials to run this example to understand it.

https://github.com/payzippy/php-sdk

Answer (score -1):

For the merchant id and secret key, you will have to reach out to us at 080-49697070 or contactus@payzippy.com. We will generate one for you and also assist you with the other processes.

Happy to Serve!
Team Payzippy.

Comment: Dear payzippy, the way you've formulated your answer is now a comment, it can be an acceptable answer if you provide a more generic description of how requesting a merchand_id work (e.g. the application procedure).